# Doctrine 2: Writing a proper Subselect

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am trying to get the total records `$qb` will return before I apply a START & LIMIT property to the query `$qb`. My `$qb` and `$totalQb` run just fine by themselves, but when I try and use `$qb` as a sub-select, I get an error thrown:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('w, se')
        ->from('Dashboard\Entity\Section', 'se')
        ->innerJoin('se.word', 'w')
        ->innerJoin('se.location', 'l');

    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->andx(
        $qb->expr()->eq('l.ignored', $ignored),
        $qb->expr()->eq('l.id', $params['l_id'])
    ), true);
```

*Everything above this line runs great by itself*

```
$totalQb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('COUNT(x.id)')
        ->from('Dashboard\Entity\Section', 'x');
```

*The above $totalQb runs fine by itself. But when I do the 
following, and try and use the $qb as a subselect of $totalQb...*

```
$dql = $qb->getDql();
$totalQb->add('where', $totalQb->expr()->exists( $dql ));
$totalSql = $totalQb->getQuery();

$sql = $totalSql->getSql();
$total = $totalSql->getSingleScalarResult();
```

**THIS IS THE ERROR THROWN**

*It's referring to the SubSelect 'exists' statement. But when I run the $dql by itself
it returns the expected results*

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 69: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got ','
```

What's the proper way to do a sub-select in my scenario?

**UPDATE**
It was suggested I add the `$totalSql->getDQL();` This is the output of that statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(x.id) FROM Dashboard\Entity\Section x WHERE 
EXISTS(
    SELECT w, se 
    FROM Dashboard\Entity\Section se 
    INNER JOIN se.word w 
    INNER JOIN se.location l 
    AND (l.ignored = 0) 
    AND (l.id = 2) 
    GROUP BY w.id, l.id
)
```

Comment: Try to dump $totalSql->getDQL() to see what's wrong with the query.

Comment: I added the output to the end of my question. It looks fine to me, but obviously I need a 2nd pair of eyes.

Comment: Yes, when I run either `$sql = $totalSql->getSql();` or `$total = $totalSql->getSingleScalarResult();` .....I get: `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 69: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got ','`

Comment: But now that I look at it again, it seems as though sub-selects cannot have more that one object selected. Need to tweak my query maybe. the sub-select returns 348 records, but the count using the sub-select says 5468 records...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the above query by changing the inner ->select to only pull from one table.